# C# correct method to compare 2 date time

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison

I have my following codes as below. It works in most scenario but today I one scenario where the `expiration_date` is `09/30/2017 00:00:00` is less than `currentDateTime` which is in `string` as `10/15/2016 14:34:19`? What is the bug on my side I just comparing as `string` ?

```
  System.DateTime expiration_date = newVer.License.Status.Expiration_Date;
  DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  currentDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  int a = expiration_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
           .CompareTo(currentDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  //MessageBox.Show("int a is :" + a);
  if (expiration_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
          .CompareTo(currentDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")) < 1)
  {
      crossDate = 1;               
      MessageBox.Show("Cross Date Alert"+ " Expiry Date Is :"+ 
                      expiration_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") 
                      + "  "+"Current Date Is :"+
                      currentDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
```

Comment: You should directly compare dates instead of converting them to strings. If you still insist on converting to strings before comparison, you should use a format that will be increasing with the increasing date i.e. `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: There is no need to `insist` to convert two dates into strings to compare two dates. Actually is "slower" because of the conversion. Don't change the domain of a value unless you cannot do otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compare datetime as you would compare numbers such as

```
DateTime expiration_date = newVer.License.Status.Expiration_Date;
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
if( expiration_date < currentDateTime)
{
   // expired 
}
```

If you need only date and not time then use

```
  DateTime expiration_date = newVer.License.Status.Expiration_Date.Date;
  DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

You can also use day difference of two date.

```
int daydiff = (int)((currentDateTime - expiration_date).TotalDays)
```

Comment: which one is better the date or date and time ?

Comment: @user5313398 I think using date only is better unless you need time as well.

Comment: @user5313398 You can also use the day difference of two date.

Comment: DateTime is more precise. It will cover your needs even if you are using only dates.

Comment: @shadow you're right but software expiration system mostly uses date only.

Comment: @AmitHasan Maybe but using datetime instead of date you don't have to visit the code again if something changes.

Comment: using date time ? I dont get you is your current code now valid?

Comment: This is kind of trivial comment but if if( expiration_date > currentDateTime) then it is still valid. 
I mean older dates are smaller than more recent :)

Answer (score 2):

Compare dates example:

```
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

            if ( d2.CompareTo(d1)>0 )
                Console.WriteLine("d2>d1");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("d2<=d1");
```

Comment: You have to compare `Dates` not `Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has a two-part answer. There may be something easier, but:

First, convert your string to a DateTime object. The DateTime class has several methods to help with this. Try ParseExact.

Then, convert the DateTime object to a Unix timestamp.

Now, you have two long ints, that you can compare, and convert the int comparison to another DateTime, and take things from there.

Answer (score 2):

don't convert to strings

```
        DateTime expiration_date = newVer.License.Status.Expiration_Date;

        if (expiration_date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cross Date Alert"+ " Expiry Date Is :"+ expiration_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "  "+"Current Date Is :"+ currentDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        }
```

Comment: @user5313398, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

.NET provides a great method for this to compare two datetime objects using the `DateTime.Compare()` method. The `DateTime.Compare()` method takes 2 datetime objects and compares both date and time or either one and returns an integer value. [DateTime.Compare()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=netcore-3.1)

I have demonstrated the same with a sample piece of code here : [Comparing 2 DateTime objects in C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420540/compare-date-is-greater-than-in-c-sharp)